# Looking for an ASCII image code formatter

Tags: code-beautification

I'm looking for a (probably old) website which had videos of a guy coding a generic program in C, and then formatting them manually to look like a movie or anime character.

Imagine things like this :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mame/quine-relay/master/QR.rb

Except not automatically generated but manually done.

If someone remembers the website where the videos are posted, I'd be grateful.

I'm also looking for a generic soft like this : github.com/asivokon/harnocode , except it would work for most languages instead of only javascript.

If someone has a clue I'd love to hear it. Thanks !

Comment: If you are looking for a free app, please add the [tag:gratis] tag, otherwise state your budget. Do you have a particular operating system in mind? Any particular programming languages you want it to work on (and, did you already try any others)?

Comment: Note that it’s off-topic here to ask for the website you have in mind. But it’s on-topic to ask for a tool that does this.

Comment: What would be the place where it's not off-topic to ask such a question ?